# Query that falls back to different table if linked server query fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, linked-server

Our test database is linked to a database owned by another department within our company. Whenever they bring their database down (like when refreshing with production data) our application goes down as well. The only thing we are doing with their database is we have a view that selects from one of their tables and we join to this view in a number of queries.

Ideally, whenever their system goes down, I'd like our view to pull from a backup of their table that exists in our database. It has slightly stale data, but at least we would be able to continue working. I thought of using a `TRY...CATCH` in the view or in a sql function, but they are not supported in those. A stored procedure might work, except that you can't join to the results of a stored procedure in queries, can you?

How can I make my `SELECT` statements fall back to a backup table when the linked server's table is unavailable?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a SQL Server Agent job to copy the data over from the other server on an ongoing basis.  That way the job would fail, but your local copy of the data would still be present.

Comment: This is a hideously inelegant approach, but have you considered the use of a table/temp table/whatever that has some kind of LinkedServerAvailable flag, setting that via your stored proc, and then making a decision based on that table's availability in your function or whatever else cares about that data?

Comment: @BrandenSchwartz, interesting... if I could determine if the linked server was online or not, maybe I could put an `IF` statement right in the view or sql function. What code would I use to determine if the linked server is online?

Comment: I'll devote some thought to this and come up with a "good"approach once I get a minute to really focus on it & try some things out , but you mentioned that you'd thought of using a TRY/CATCH except that you can't do that in views & functions?  Maybe set your "available" bit with a stored proc using a try/catch around SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM your linked table, if it succeeds it's available, pull from the live stuff, if not pull your local stale data. That could make your execution plans a little wonky and inefficient though. Are these views being called from your application's code, I'm assuming?

Comment: @MaxVernon, it's a whole lot of data that would need to be copied and the test users would see stale data most of the time. I don't know that it's a viable solution for us.

Comment: Since we're brainstorming here, maybe we could create a SQL Server Agent job that runs every 5-10 minutes that actually alters the view to pull from the linked server or the backup table depending on whether the linked server is online. That might actually work for us.

Comment: You could experiment to determine the ideal amount of time between runs of the job; perhaps you could run it every 30seconds (use a `WHERE 1=0` clause to not actually return rows to the job.)

Comment: I don't think I even need a query. I can just call `sp_testlinkedserver @srvr` in a `TRY...CATCH` and alter the view accordingly. I suppose I'll have to save the previous state somewhere and compare it with the new value so I don't alter the view every time.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, depending on how much flexibility you have in your application you could display a message along the lines of 'live data is unavailable, you're getting stale stuff from [last replication date/time]' so that users don't see old data and make bad decisions assuming it's current.

Comment: I just thought of this potential concern, though: if you're hitting sp_testlinkedserver every 5-10 minutes, is it going to be a problem if the application is unavailable for 4 minutes or 9 minutes after you get a successful ping and then one minute later the other team takes their DB offline for maintenance? The only ways I can see around that would be to ping the linked server immediately before every call or get the other team to push an update to your "status" table whenever they know they're taking it down.

Comment: Since this is just a test environment, we can handle a few minutes of down time. I just don't want to be down for a few hours every time they restore their database. If this was production, we'd definitely need to take your concern into consideration and probably have them update the DB status in one of our tables like you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was to create a SQL Server Agent job that calls `sp_testlinkedserver` in a `TRY...CATCH` every few minutes and if it's down we alter the view to point to our backup table and if it's up, we alter it to point to the "live" data again. We also track the previous state so we only alter the view if the state has changed. It works pretty slick.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.. I don't need the solution right now but I can see how it would be valuable!